# Kotlin convert Date or Calendar to firebase timestamp

Tags: date, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, calendar, timestamp

i have this problem in many of my apps, i search and try many things and nothing works.
I have have a Datepicker in my android app written in kotlin, i get year month and day, but i need to save this in Timestamp in firestore database, to query the results by date for example, i have no problem in converting Timestamp to Date or to day month and year. The problem is i can't find a way to create the Timestamp with seconds and nanoseconds, with the calendar i have or the Date() i'm looking for something like Timestamp.toDate() but like this for example Calendar.toTimestamp (firebase)
Thanks for reading this

Comment: Already try this too val myTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(2019, 0, 1)) . Unresolved reference Timestamp but Timestamp.now() works

Comment: I can upload a Timestamp to firestore using Date(year, month,day) but android studio says is deprecated in Java, and the year is 3920 instead 2020 , doesn't work well

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this, in datepicker I set day month and year to a Calendar, then I pass the Calendar to Date() and its accurate now.

```
    val cal = c.timeInMillis
    val timeStampNacimiento = Timestamp(Date(cal))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Timestamp constructor that accepts a Date](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#Timestamp(java.util.Date)).

```
new Timestamp(date)
```

Comment: I don't need Timestamp to Date, i already use that, i need Date or Calendar to Timestamp to save in firestore the Timestamp

Comment: The Java platform isn't going to provide any methods that know about Firestore timestamps.  You'll have to use the Timestamp constructor. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks i try this, val a =  Date(year, month,day)
            productoCompleto["test"] = Timestamp(a) , and instead 6/1/1981 it save timestamp 7/26/3920 , i save year month and date in separate fields and they are fine, when i use Date(year, month, day) something weird happen

Comment: when i debbug a: "Tue Jul 27 00:00:00 GMT -03:00 3920" year: 2020 month: 6 day: 27

Comment: That sounds like a new problem.  I suggest posting a while new question with your complete code and observations.

Answer (score 0):

If `Timestamp.fromDate()` isn't working, try the constructor.

```kotlin
new Timestamp(seconds: number, nanoseconds: number): Timestamp
```

So for your case: get the seconds from your `Date`, then set the nanoseconds to 0.

```kotlin
new Timestamp(new Date(yyyy, mm, dd).getTime() / 1000, 0)
```

Comment: I tried this and still having the year problem, not need full code, the year month and day are correct, i storing in my db and they are fine, i check in debug and they are fine, when i use   val a = Timestamp(Date(year, month, day).time / 1000, 0) its store wrong year, in debug is telling the correct year but stores year 3920 in timestamp instead 2020 or 1981 it happens with any year i choose , but the var year is ok always.